# Material UI multiple Select MenuItem ref error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

Lately, I'm getting without a reason this error from opening a multiple Select in React+Next.js using Material UI:

```
Error: Argument appears to not be a ReactComponent. Keys: retry
```

This appears to be an error related to a ref.
It happens on both the Select I do have on that page and both the select on another one.

This error **only happens** when I try to open a Select which has MenuItems inside; if it doesn't, it just doesn't happen (the select opens but it's, obviously, empty). And the error never happens if I don't open the Select, it probably happens when trying to render the MenuItems.

```
const FormControlLabel = dynamic(() => import("@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel"));
const InputLabel = dynamic(() => import('@material-ui/core/InputLabel'));
const MenuItem = dynamic(() => import('@material-ui/core/MenuItem'));

/* Then, in render... */

<FormControl id="selected-genres-wrapper">
    <InputLabel htmlFor="selected-genres-input">Generi</InputLabel>
    <Select
        multiple
        value={this.state.selectedEdited && this.state.selectedEdited.genres ? this.state.selectedEdited.genres : this.state.selected.genres}
        onChange={this.genresSelect}
        input={<FilledInput variant="filled" id="selected-genres-input" />}
        renderValue={selected => (
            <div>
                {selected.map(value => (
                    <Chip key={value} label={value} />
                ))}
            </div>
        )}
    >
        {this.genres.map(name => (
            <MenuItem key={name} value={name}>
                {name}
            </MenuItem>
        ))}
    </Select>
</FormControl>
```

The error itself just doesn't make sense because it's an internal error with no kind of help to debug or prevent it in any way.

I also tried updating Material UI core (I was using 4.6, now I'm using 4.11) but really nothing changed.

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Menu.js line referenced in the stacktrace](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.6.0/packages/material-ui/src/Menu/Menu.js#L123) is code where the `Menu` is cloning the child `MenuItem` elements. The error is due to your dynamic import of `MenuItem`.

If you replace the dynamic import with:

```
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
```

it should work fine.

Comment: Many thanks! It was it.
It's a really stupid mistake, guess I learnt something from it.